# Dreamspark Windows 7 on several computer at once

Tags: windows-7, msdn, dreamspark

I read the dreamspark term of use but I can't find whether or not I can do it.
I know that I can activate the same license 10 times but can I use a windows 7 pro x64 with the same license on 2 computer at once?

thanks

Comment: Don't think so. You're also bound by the EULA of the product itself as well and non-volume Windows keys can only be activated on one computer at a time. I transfered my dreamspark premium (MSDN-AA then) Windows 7 key once, and I had to use telephone activation to confirm that I am transfering the license to a new computer.

Comment: Weird, I just changed my motherboard and graphic card and reinsalled the same OS with the same licence, activation went well.